# Java CRUD MVC, Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Tags: java

Tengo un CRUD normal y corriente, al momento de hacer la parte de buscar tengo un pequeño problema, quiero que busque en la bd con cualquier dato verdad? o sea si digita el nombre pues tal sale el resto de datos, si busca por telefono pues igual sale el resto de datos, todos esos los tengo como String, el de cedula que esta comentado si lo tengo por integer, entonces ... Cómo le hago para que lo busque? al ponerlo normal me marca de una error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Le hago un parseInt y tampoco, o sea funciona ya normal el de cedula, pero ahora no me funcionan los demas todos los String

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: try & catch es la solucion a ello. Tambien puedes usar NumberUtils de apache commons.

Comment: Hola Bienvenido a Stackoverflow , te invito a hacer el [tour] , y leer un poco mas de [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , preguntas pegando imagenes son catalogadas de baja calidad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en este caso veo que usted quiere utilizar cualquiera de los campos de formulario para su búsqueda ,el problema se encuentra que al presionar el botón buscar el String de Cédula está vacío y por lo tanto no se puede convertir a entero,yo usaria algo asi.

Primero comprobamos que el Campo este cargado y luego convertir a Entero.

```
try{


    if(!frm.txtCedula.getText().isEmpty()){
       objeto.setCedula(Integer.parseInt(frm.txtCedula.getText())); 
    }


    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.err.println("Error:"+ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Usamos try catch por cualquier cosa ,luego lo que hacemos es preguntar si es txtCedula está vacío y si no es asi pues que no haga nada.

Answer (score 0):

Esa excepcion corresponde a que estas poniendo un dato erroneo, ej. en un campo de tipo int estas poniendo un dato tipo String o vicecersa!.